# PIN or Valgrind with Managed C++?

Tags: c++, valgrind, instrumentation

I was wondering what experiences you have had using instrumentation tools with managed C++?

- PIN: http://www.pintool.org/
- Valgrind: http://www.valgrind.org

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind is Linux only with some experimental support for BSDs and Mac OSX, so it looks you are out of luck here, unless you have [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) :)

Comment: @Nikolai I don't understand the mono reference.  Does it support C++ now?

Comment: @Duck, managed C++ comes from .NET, right? Mono project is re-implementation of .NET under Linux (mostly). Though 'mononucleosis, also called "mono," is a common viral illness' - that was a joke :)

Comment: Managed C++ isn't supported outside of the Microsoft .NET runtime at the moment. In fact I doubt anyone else will ever support it since it was discontinued and replaced by C++/CLI in Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Running Valgrind under Wine might be what you are looking for. See also [Running Wine under Valgrind](http://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_and_Valgrind).